# Use GCP services with python and proxy

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, proxy

At work we have a proxy, classic setup.

I try to access a file in a GCS bucket or read/write on a BigQuery Table with my python script. Everything is woking fine on another network.

I have setup my env with the proxy's URL for `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` on Ubuntu.
I have set also the value for `apt` and even for the browser. I can `apt update`, `git clone`... but something as simple as `df = pd.read_csv("gs://.......")` doesn't work.

I even configure `gcloud` to setup proxy's value.

```
$ gcloud config list      
[compute]
region = europe-west1
zone = europe-west1-c
[core]
account = me@myself.org
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = world-anhilation-666
[proxy]
address = proxy.net
port = 8080
type = http

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

The script runs for more than 10min and gave me the error :
`Cannot connect to host www.googleapis.com:443 ssl:default [Network is unreachable]`

Answer (score 1):

You could try several options for solving this issue

Your internet firewall is blocking the connection to google api: try pinging android.googleapis.com in your laravel host. or curl -v gcm-http.googleapis.com if it doesn't response, most likely it is blocked.

Open your the port for google api to work, make sure 443 is open, 5528-2230. It might need to be configured in your firewall

gcm-http.googleapis.com has a lot of ip addresses, so you need to allow the connection from these ip addresses. This is one of their ip address:172.217.24.234 . You can monitor the ip addresses in your firewall.

you can find the range of google api IP addresses on this links[1] and [2]

[1]https://whois.domaintools.com/172.217.24.234
[2]http://whois.domaintools.com/216.58.196.202

Comment: Hi my Laravel host ? You mean localhost right ? I'm no PHP man here.
I will try and come back to you. Unfortunally if I have to modify anything in the firewall/proxy I won't be able, it's the holding of the company that handle that. To far from my position to contact them....